# Unexpected behavior in TSQL trigger using cursor: AND operator with values 1 AND 0 evaluates to true

Tags: t-sql, triggers, cursor, bit, logical-operators

I have been trying to debug some questionable database transactions produced by a trigger and when stepping through the T-SQL have encountered unexpected results. After obtaining values from the cursor via `FETCH NEXT FROM Updated_Cursor` , I enter a while loop and then for each row fetched from the cursor I evaluate two variables to determine whether an insertion will be made after some processing as follows:

```
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
      IF (@first_indicator > 0 AND @second_indicator >0)
      BEGIN
              --processing and insert occurs here
```

In debug mode, stepping through the code, I can see that when the value of `@first_indicator=1` and `@second_indicator=0` this condition is evaluating to true which does not make sense to me. It is resulting in duplicate and erroneous rows being inserted. The two variables are `bit` datatype, which I feel may be relevant, but I am lost as to why this is happening.

Comment: well, your code has `second_indicator` and your "see that when the value of" is `second_indictor` (missing the `a`)... if that's not a typo, then you've got two different variables.

Comment: OT: but try not to use cursors in triggers, 99 times out of 100 it's plain wrong.

Comment: Also, the issue was fixed when the condition was changed from:
`IF (@first_indicator > 0 AND @second_indicator >0)`
To:
`IF (@first_indicator = 1 AND @second_indicator =1)`
 fixed the issue, but I would still like to know what T-SQL is doing that broke the first evaluation.

Comment: Cursors aren't inherently bad: it's the uses they are often put to that's bad. I'd use one if I had too. But for some reason I can nearly always find a way of doing it the set-based way.  Yes: under the covers the SQL engine runs loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When pulling your code out of the cursor like so:

```
DECLARE @f BIT = 1
DECLARE @s BIT = 0

IF(@f>0 AND @s>0) PRINT 'GH';
```

It works as expected and does not print. Are you sure that you are looking at the right variables at the right time when the if statement gets executed?

Also, the two `IF` statements you mention in your comment are not equivalent. Therefore I am not exactly sure what your actual question is.

Comment: You may have seen the second comment before I corrected the typo. They should have equivalent evaluations two variables now. I was certain I was looking at the correct values, but when I place the statement in a separate query as you suggest, I can see it evaluates as expected, so I am no longer sure what was happening or if my original question is valid.